# Making a screenshot from QGIS2web Openlayers map

Tags: javascript, openlayers, qgis2web

I would like to make a screenshot from my Openlayers map

My code so far looks like this:

```
    <div id="map">
    <div id="screenshot">
        <div id="popup" class="ol-popup">
            <a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a>
            <div id="popup-content"></div>
    </div>
     </div>


     <script>
      function makeScreenshot() {
      html2canvas(document.getElementById("screenshot"), {scale: 2}).then(canvas => {
     canvas.id = "map";
     canvas.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
     var main = document.getElementById("map");
     while (main.firstChild) {
      main.removeChild(main.firstChild); 
     }
    console.log(main);
    main.appendChild(canvas);
   });
   }

   document.getElementById("a-make").addEventListener('click', function()
   {
   document.getElementById("a-make").style.display = "none";
   makeScreenshot();
   document.getElementById("a-download").style.display = "inline";
  }, false);

  document.getElementById("a-download").addEventListener('click', function()
  {
  this.href = document.getElementById("map").querySelector('canvas').toDataURL();

  this.download = "canvas-image.png";
  }, false);
       </script>
```

The map comes from qgis2web.js  file.

The console says nothing, but the map is completely blank when clicked at: generate screenshot button.

Why can't I grab the Qgis2web map content in  section properly?

[image]

Comment: What sort of layers do u have on your map when you execute the export?

Comment: basemap and some drawing layers and 14 another layers, which come from QGIS export along with the QGIS2web olugin. They're grouped in the "layers".

Comment: You may have basemaps that do not allow exporting. For example I know that OSM is capable to export while google maps not. If you get basemaps from local geoserver propably it is not CORS enabled. Try to see if you can execute the export while having in your map only OSM as a basemap.

Comment: I have an OSM as the basemap. Te problem is, that I don't know neither how to check if it's CORS enabled nor how to make it enabled (the right place, where I should put the crossorigins:"Anonymous"). Looks like I can't execute anything related to the QGIS2web map embedded in the div.

Comment: QGIS embeds map layers on a desktop app , not on the web. So some layers if they are not CORS enabled will not work when exposed on the web. For OSM I can guaranty  it will work, but to fix any other layer you need access to the server generating those layes.

Comment: I believe so, that it might be an internal QGIS2web issue. Thank you for the hint anyway :)